# How would I create an MVC route that directs all requests to a single method on a single controller and resolve the route parameter as {id}?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

given the following examples

http://my.url/123
or
http://my.url/abc

1. how would i configure a route that passes either request to the same action method on the same controller
2. how would I resolve 123 or abc as the input paramter (id) to this action method

   public ActionResult Index(String id)
   {
   ViewData["Message"] = id;
   return View();
   }

So if I went to http://my.url/123 it would print "123", etc.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239025/asp-net-mvc-routing-url-only-with-string-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work, however you may break other routes as you're essentially doing a catch-all on the first part of the path:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "id-route",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", id = "{id}"
});
```